# iterating data from 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my index I'm trying to iterate through records through records in 2 models, job and employer. I've set up a has_many relationship.

Rails its throwing a **undefined method `each'** for #

**job model**

```
attr_accessible :title, :location   
belongs_to :employer
```

**employer model**

```
attr_accessible :companyname
has_many :jobs
```

**job controller**

```
def index
@jobs = Job.find(:all, :include => :employer)
```

**index**

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
<%= job.title %>
<%= job.location %>

  <% job.employer.each do |employer| %>
  <% employer.companyname %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which method is undefined?

Comment: edit: undefined method `each' for #<Employer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a job has one employer, not many. That's what the belongs_to means. See this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) about setting up actual many-to-many relationships.

But I think in your case you *do* want it to be a one-to-many. Why would a job have multiple employers? Instead, just output the single employer company name.

**More Info**

You still want a belongs_to on your Job model. belongs_to go on models that have a foreign key referencing some other model. In this case, your Job model has an ID pointing at an Employer (it has an employer_id field). That has_one or has_many associations are for when no foreign key exists on the model but a relationship still exists.

So your Job model has a method called `employer` (singular) but not `employers` (plural) because it *belongs to* a single employer. An employer `has many` jobs under them, so the has_many association gives you a `jobs` (plural) method, not a `job` (singular) method.

The link I posted for the Rails guide does an excellent job of showing more of this, with more details and explanation, and more examples.

**Addtional Code Bit**

With the above, you will want to change your code to be like this:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= job.title %>
  <%= job.location %>

  <%= job.employer.companyname %>
<% end %>
```

Notice how you can go straight to accessing the attributes on the employer that you want. And that will do it!

Comment: You're correct, a job has one employer. So I need to replace belongs_to with  has_one ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does make sense, but I'm still confused as to why my current code doesn't work. As far as I can see, jobs are plural and employer is singular?

Comment: Oh that's because a singular method implies only one object is being returned, not an array. You can't iterate over a single object.

Comment: *facepalm* my excuse is I'm new to all this! just one more.. so how do I output a singuar employer within the jobs iteration?

Comment: hm now it's throwing a "undefined method `companyname' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: That's because your specific job instead has no employer. You either need to add a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence) so that you can ensure each job has an employer, or if no employer is okay, you need to guard against that. A nice one-liner is this: `job.employer.try(:companyname)`, but using an if (`if job.employer.nil?`) works too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this in the rails console?

```
Job.last.employer
```

If that doesn't work your relationship isn't set up properly.

Does your Job model have an employer_id field? Did you run `rake db:migrate` to make sure all your migrations are run?

Comment: Job.last.employer succeeds in the console. The Job model has an employer_id field. rake db:migrate succeeds